# Problems uploading files to Django from React/Redux frontend with axios

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, axios

I've got a django project set up using react/redux on my frontend and I need to be able to upload multiple files from the frontend which are read on the backend (not saved to the database or anything) so that I can do some server-side processing. However, I just can't seem to get the files in the django request handler. I'm sure it's something silly to do with my headers or the way I try post it but I've read like 30 other SO questions with similar titles and I can't seem to make mine work.

I've got a FileUploader component that (seems to) allows me to upload the files and store them in my state. On hitting the upload button, I coerce it into formData (as most django sources said to do this) and fire off my post request.

My React component

```
export class FileUploader extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    files: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    this.props.uploadFiles(event.target.files);
  };

  fileUploadHandler = event => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("files", this.props.files);
    console.log(this.props.files);
    console.log("formData", formData);
    this.props.addSubmission(formData);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="file-uploader">
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
        <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  files: state.submissions.files
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { uploadFiles, addSubmission }
)(FileUploader);
```

My post request in my redux actions:

```
export const addSubmission = submission => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/submission_stats/add_submission/", submission)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_SUBMISSION,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

My Django Viewset:

```
class SubmissionStatsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SubmissionStats.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = SubmissionStatsSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def add_submission(self, request, pk=None):
        #at this point, request.FILES is always empty
```

What I'm expecting to happen is to be then be able to access these files in my django request handler under the request.FILES attribute. However this is always empty, even though my headers appear to have formData being sent. I've tried several other things that had been suggested, such as adding a enctype="multipart/form-data" header, or some content-type header to my axios post. I also tried using a normal form and abandoning the react/redux stuff but I haven't been able to make it work. I imagine it's something quite simple because I don't see why uploading a file shouldn't be a simple thing to do but I've sort of fried myself out here and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Does `console.log("formData", formData);` show that your FormData has actual data in it?

Comment: @Hybrid Sorry for the delay, my internet got cutoff for a few days (thank you ISP). Now that you mention it doesn't look like it does. I'm not really familiar with FormData, but my print looks like: FormData{} and just has the __proto__ inside it. Am I misusing the syntax somehow? I just followed the Mozilla docs

Comment: I've also tried appending the files individually but the result is the same